# BSTR memory leak in atldbsch.h - what to do?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am running Deleaker application to find and fix memory leaks in an application.
Now, it finds a lot of BSTR leaks with roots in the Open()-function of the Microsoft CRestrictions class (atldbsch.h file).

If one looks there one can notice that it takes 7 LPCTSTR parameters, which are then used like this:

```
pVariant = m_pvarRestrictions + 1;
.
.
pVariant->bstrVal = ::SysAllocString(T2COLE_EX_DEF(lpszParam1));
```

This is done for all seven such parameters (where the number 1 is increased every time).

The destructor is simply doing

```
delete[] m_pvarRestrictions;
```

but the BSTRs allocated via ::SysAllocString() are never freed though via calls to ::SysFreeStr()

Am I missing something or is there a leak, and in that case how should it be handled in this case?

Comment: After checking [the header file](https://github.com/dpalma/sge/blob/master/3rdparty/atl/atldbsch.h) I would argue it's a bug in the Microsoft ATL code.

Comment: After checking the same header file and seeing `CComVariant* m_pvarRestriction;` as the declaration of that member variable, I would argue it is *not* a bug; the destructor of `CComVariant` will clean up the allocated BSTR values provided the variant-type member (`vt`) is properly set correctly to `VT_BSTR` (which by all accounts, it is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/dpalma/sge/blob/master/3rdparty/atl/atldbsch.h, `m_pvarRestrictions` is defined as `ATL::CComVariant *`, so the `ATL::CComVariant` destructor should be cleaning up the `BSTR` variants (the code is correctly setting `vt` to `VT_BSTR`). That is, the `CComVariant` destructor calls `CComVariant::Clear` which calls `VariantClear`.

Thus, there should not be a memory leak here -- the code looks correct. It is likely an issue with Deleaker having problems detecting this pattern.

Comment: Just tested Deleaker 3.0.66.00 with a simple application and no leaks shown, so VariantClear is processed as expected: BSTR str = SysAllocString(L"something"); VARIANT vt; vt.bstrVal = str; vt.vt = VT_BSTR; VariantClear(&vt);

Answer (score 1):

After checking the code I would say that no leaks here because m_pvarRestrictions is a pointer to array of CComVariant, and this array is deleted via delete[], so destructor for each CComVariant is called. CComVariant::~CComVariant() calls VariantClear that itself frees BSTR if this VARIANT contains it.

Then I've checked how Deleaker (version 3.0.66.0) works with CComVariant, here my code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CComVariant* v = new CComVariant(L"123");
    delete v;

    return 0;
}
```

No leaks are shown. Probably you've tried old version of Deleaker.

If I remove delete v, then I see two leaks: heap memory and BSTR.

Comment: I am using Deleaker 3.0.54 so yes there could be a difference perhaps.
I don't know if it makes any difference but my client code is creating a new CTableConstraints and then calling open() on it (followed by a close()) so I thought if that somehow could change anything. 

I should perhaps try a newer version of Deleaker if possible.
I read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xda6xzx7.aspx, and therefore it seemed like it would be the responsibility of the client code (in this case CRestrictions class) to free up the BSTRs. But okey then.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you set the pVariant type also to VT_BSTR. This isn't shown in the code. If you don't set the type, this will cause a leak.

If pVariant is in fact a pointer to CComVariant this code should work:

```
*pVariant = T2COLE_EX_DEF(lpszParam1);
```

And in this case VT_BSTR type is set and the destruction will clean up the variant.